# Formula for the coefficients of $m$th order the central difference scheme

Tags: numerical-methods, binomial-coefficients

In a paper I'm reading, I found the following formula for the coefficients of the $m$th order central difference scheme. For all $\ell \in \{-m,-m+1, \dots, m-1,m\}$:
$$a_{\ell} = \begin{cases}
\frac{(-1)^{\ell-1}}{\ell} \cdot \frac{\binom{m}{|\ell|}}{\binom{m+|\ell|}{|\ell|}}, & \text{if } \ell \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
In the paper, it is not proven that these are indeed the coefficients of the $m$th order central difference scheme, so I want to prove this myself, i.e., I want to prove for $k \in \{0,1, \dots, 2m\}$:
$$\sum_{\ell=-m}^m a_{\ell}\ell^k = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } k = 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Numerical simulation strongly suggests that it's true, however I have no idea how one would go about proving it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.